# How to show only mp3 file using MediaStore?

Tags: android

In my app , I am displaying all audio files using `MediaStore` and `ListAdaptor` and `CursorLoader` . But it shows all audio files (m4a,wav,ogg). I only want to show mp3 files . How can I do so ?

```
String[] from = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
int[] to = {android.R.id.text1};

CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,sourceUri,null,null,null,MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cursor,from,to,CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 9):

Please try below code

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

String[] projection = null;

String sortOrder = null;

String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";

String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3"); 

String[] selectionArgsMp3 = new String[]{ mimeType };

Cursor allmp3Files = cr.query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsmp3, sortOrder);
```

Answer (score -1):

See [THIS](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory) example, which displays only provided file extensions list.