# Filtering mp3 files from MediaStore

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am using this code to get all the audio files from the device.

```
ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor musicCursor = contentResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);
```

I want to get only .mp3 files, how can we filter the output of the query to get only .mp3 files

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this question :

[How to show only mp3 file using MediaStore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14935323/how-to-show-only-mp3-file-using-mediastore)

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

String[] projection = null;

String sortOrder = null;

String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";

String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3"); 

String[] selectionArgsMp3 = new String[]{ mimeType };

Cursor allmp3Files = cr.query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsmp3, sortOrder);
```

Comment: can we add one more mimeType ".m4a" to selectionArgsMp3. I tried to add in the array but i am getting this error "Cannot bind argument at index 2 because the index is out of range"